# code to get DATE in which output should be generated with the DATE which is exactly 2 days later

Tags: xslt, mapping, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

if user sends a current date(24-09-2021) as input , but when generating the output the date should that we should get will be 2 days later. which is 26-09-2021. Kindly help how to code in Xslt.

Comment: If you happen to be using a processor that supports XSLT 2.0 or higher, you can use  `<xsl:value-of select="xs:date($inputDate) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P2D')"/>`. Note that the input date must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: will above code matches this rule:  Date +2 (add 2 days). Format YYYYMMDD

Comment: The initial format is YYYY-MM-DD, but you can change it using the `format-date()` function.

Comment: <ShipmentDate>
          <xsl:call-template name="FormatDateToCore">
            <xsl:with-param name="date">
              <xsl:value-of select="s0:ShipmentDate" />
            <xsl:value-of select="s0:date($ShipmentDate) + s0:dayTimeDuration('P2D')"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </ShipmentDate>
using code like this. but getting error. can you tell me how to add it

Comment: No. I need to see a [mcve]. Either edit your question and add all the necessary code there or post a new one. And if you're getting an error, post also the exact error message.